# How can I use a variable as a comparator in python?

Tags: python, comparison

I have some KPIs and for some, beyond the target value is good while for others it's bad.

Can I do something like

```
comparator = '<'
value = 100
target = 200
```

and then go on to say

```
value comparator target
```

So that python sees this as `100 < 200` and returns True?

For context, I have a table of KPIs which follow the format:

```
KPI1: < 100 On Target, > 110 Action Required

KPI2: > 50 On Target, <
```

and I plan to loop through them and through their associated data to apply RAG ratings.

Comment: The `operator` module provides function versions of each comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use first-class methods. This allows you to skip importing the `operator` module, and is safer than using eval():

```py
def lt(a, b): return a < b
def gt(a, b): return a > b
def eq(a, b): return a == b

comparator = lt
print(comparator(4, 5))  # >>> True
```

Comment: These functions are already predefined in the `operator` module.

Comment: If he wanted to use custom comparators, this would be the way to go.

Answer (score -2):

This can work (using eval)

```
comparator_1  = '>'
x = 7
y = 12
print(eval('{} {} {}'.format(x,comparator_1,y)))
comparator_2  = '<'
print(eval('{} {} {}'.format(x,comparator_2,y)))
```

output

```
False
True
```

Comment: There's no need for `eval` here.

Comment: @chepner It is an option (But I agree it is not the best one..)

Comment: Just because something is *an* option doesn't mean it's a *good* one or should be recommended.